# python requests ('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

I'm trying to connect to a server using a certificate and a private key using the requests module but I'm having issues.

My code:

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()
s.cert = (certificate_file, key_file)
s.headers = {'Content-Type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8',
             'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate'}
r = s.post(url=url, data=request_body)
```

Error:

```
Error: [('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')]
```

The weird thing is that the same certificate and key seems to be working with the http.client module

```
import ssl
import http.client

request_url = ...
request_headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate',
}
request_body = ...


context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
context.load_cert_chain(certfile=certificate_file, keyfile=key_file)

connection = http.client.HTTPSConnection(host, port=443, context=context)

connection.request(method="POST", url=request_url,
                   headers=request_headers, body=request_body)

response = connection.getresponse()
```

Any ideas or suggestions would be welcome

Comment: The key and certificate do not matter since they define the client certificate but the error message is instead about a server certificate which cannot be validated. Impossible to say way based on the current information what exactly the problem, i.e. it might be a wrong setup on the server side, (untrusted) self-signed certificate or bad local trust store. It might also be a problem that you access the server in the wrong way, i.e. without SNI.

Comment: "Any ideas or suggestions would be welcome" Start by posting the certificate returned. Certificates are public information, there is nothing gained by hiding them but seeing them helps in debugging to at least see in which case you are, as Steffen commented.

Comment: You can also try with `openssl s_client` with and without the `-servername` (that enables SNI, which is on by default in 1.1.1 so here you can use `-noservername` if needed) so that you see what is the certificate returned in both cases, and what openssl itself thinks about the certificate.